# java Calling another class's method to print from same package

Tags: java, class, object, methods, import

So I opened a package within several folders of classes to make methods however I want to use main class for bug testing or training however I'm still  learning. I knew that there are some ways to create objects or import ways but the web samples didnt fit my instance. Here is my 1st class in same package.Sorry for turkish keywords.

```
package müsvette.pkg23.pkg02;

public class Müsvette2302 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Özyinelemeli f(5)=" + f1(5));

    }   
}
```

AND 2nd Class added

```
package müsvette.pkg23.pkg02;
public class ozyinelemeli {

    int f1(int n){
        if(n==0) return 0;
        if(n==1) return 1;
        if(n==2) return 1;
        return f1(n-1)+f1(n/2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: Create an object of the second class and call it's function from your main method. What's the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `f1` on an object/instance of `ozyinelemeli` which you create using the keyword, `new`.

Do it as follows:

```
package müsvette.pkg23.pkg02;

public class Müsvette2302 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Özyinelemeli f(5)=" + new ozyinelemeli().f1(5));
    }
}
```

**Alternatively,**

```
package müsvette.pkg23.pkg02;

public class Müsvette2302 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ozyinelemeli obj = new ozyinelemeli();
        System.out.println("Özyinelemeli f(5)=" + obj.f1(5));
    }
}
```

**Note:** I recommend you follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the class name, `ozyinelemeli` should be `Ozyinelemeli` as per the naming convention.

Comment: First of all thank you and really appreciated.

Comment: I will although in this sense of calling with objects may i prevent adding any tools 
to like ; System.out.println("Özyinelemeli f(5)=" + f1(5));

Comment: What do you mean by tools?